# What noun applies to all things transformed by human hands

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, technology, philosophy

As opposed to naturally occurring or unintentionally produced by human activity.  It would include commodities, products, merchandise, parts, materials, etc.

Specifically a thing that has any work put into it.

Comment: You might like my [answer to a slightly different question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/70283/18696)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: So, *anthrofacta*?

Comment: I really do, the affix arte in artifact does contribute the use of skill though. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want an adjective or a noun.

**artificial**

> Adjective: **artificial**  aa(r)-tu'fi-shul
>
> 1. Contrived by art rather than nature
>
>    "artificial flavouring"; "an artificial diamond"; "artificial fibers";
>
>    - unreal
> 2. Artificially formal
>
>    "that artificial humility that her husband hated";
>
>    - contrived, hokey [N. Amer], stilted
> 3. Not arising from natural growth or characterized by vital processes

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=artificial)

---

**artifact**

> Noun: **artifact**  'aar-ti,fakt
>
> Usage: N. Amer (elsewhere: artefact)
>
> 1. A man-made object taken as a whole
>
>    - artefact [Brit]
> 2. Something that appears in a scientific result that is not a true feature of thing being studied, but instead a result of the experimental or analysis method, or observational error
>
>    "the method has no artifacts from using a low-resolution pixelization";
>
>    - artefact [Brit]

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=artifact)

Comment: I think *artifact* is really close, but it connotes small objects (like pottery).

Comment: atifacts is really close, could be bang on.  I consider it more disconnected from personal production but I'm probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

"**Man-made**"

[> "manufactured, created, or constructed by human beings; specifically

> :synthetic man-made fibers"][1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man-made)

Answer (score 0):

'Produce' has a meaning which covers both agriculture and commerce, media and the arts.

> https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/produce

The single word is either a noun or a verb.

Anything that has work put into it is covered by it.

Comment: also good but maybe too general, not limited to human activity but any activity.